# multiple query in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have question about multiple query in node.js.

now, I'm developing a dash board web application and because various board, which is related with different table is shown on one page, multiple query is required.

I've seen the way using "async.parallel" but couldn't understand enough.
I need more detail sample code.
I use mysql as database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Bimar Kumar.
Thank you for your answer.
I think your suggested way is well working.

anyway I solved the problem using async module as follows.

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        var queryData = 'SELECT * FROM table1';
        client.query(queryData, function (err, rows1) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            return callback(null, rows1);
        });
    },
    function(callback) {
        client.query('SELECT * FROM table2', function (err, rows2) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            return callback(null, rows2);
        });
    },
    function(callback) {
          ...
    }
], function(error, callbackResults) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        response.send(ejs.render(data, {
          queryResult1 : callbackResults[0],
          queryResult1 : callbackResults[1],
               ...
      }));
    }
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to use prmomise here.Better refer this link https://www.guru99.com/node-js-promise-generator-event.html